# How to utilize groupby, perform calculation on only certain rows and keep all column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to calculate some percent change of time series data in python pandas. But i'm having trouble doing it via groupby and applying the calculations correctly on the right time period data.
Here is the dataframe I currently have:

```
     A      B           C           D
0    ACTUAL 2018-03-01  249.498000  0.040000
1    ACTUAL 2018-06-01  251.134000  0.040000
2    ACTUAL 2018-09-01  252.010000  0.037000
3    ACTUAL 2018-12-01  252.723000  0.039000
4    ACTUAL 2019-03-01  254.148000  0.038000
5    TDA_D5 2019-03-01  253.393661  0.038667
6    TDA_D5 2019-06-01  254.329314  0.038229
7    TDA_D5 2019-09-01  254.784295  0.038974
8    TDA_D5 2019-12-01  254.988064  0.040149
9    TDA_D5 2020-03-01  255.158740  0.041696
10   TDA_D5 2020-06-01  255.243512  0.043405
11   TDA_D5 2020-09-01  255.360638  0.045753
12   TDA_D5 2020-12-01  255.445890  0.047833
13   TDA_D5 2021-03-01  255.700028  0.051772
14   TDA_D5 2021-06-01  256.001398  0.054357
15   TDA_D5 2021-09-01  256.347487  0.056077
16   TDA_D5 2021-12-01  256.792392  0.056796
17   TDA_D5 2022-03-01  257.314624  0.057218
18   TDA_D5 2022-06-01  257.922474  0.057385
19   TDA_U5 2019-03-01  253.393661  0.038667
20   TDA_U5 2019-06-01  255.882782  0.036118
21   TDA_U5 2019-09-01  258.415239  0.034246
22   TDA_U5 2019-12-01  261.090022  0.032766
23   TDA_U5 2020-03-01  264.033754  0.031713
24   TDA_U5 2020-06-01  267.157258  0.030939
25   TDA_U5 2020-09-01  270.563024  0.030997
26   TDA_U5 2020-12-01  274.090429  0.031201
27   TDA_U5 2021-03-01  277.877144  0.032869
28   TDA_U5 2021-06-01  281.790593  0.033901
29   TDA_U5 2021-09-01  285.838634  0.034656
30   TDA_U5 2021-12-01  289.992294  0.035058
31   TDA_U5 2022-03-01  294.235605  0.035529
32   TDA_U5 2022-06-01  298.547907  0.036048
33  TD_BASE 2019-03-01  253.393661  0.038667
34  TD_BASE 2019-06-01  255.119961  0.037143
35  TD_BASE 2019-09-01  256.589769  0.036490
36  TD_BASE 2019-12-01  257.949582  0.036184
37  TD_BASE 2020-03-01  259.351461  0.036187
38  TD_BASE 2020-06-01  260.702463  0.036312
39  TD_BASE 2020-09-01  262.093917  0.037062
40  TD_BASE 2020-12-01  263.422911  0.037667
41  TD_BASE 2021-03-01  264.883181  0.039809
42  TD_BASE 2021-06-01  266.351643  0.041000
43  TD_BASE 2021-09-01  267.828346  0.041699
44  TD_BASE 2021-12-01  269.313336  0.041867
45  TD_BASE 2022-03-01  270.806660  0.042033
46  TD_BASE 2022-06-01  272.308363  0.042199
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to take groupby on column A, if it's not equal to 'ACTUAL', take the first 4 rows of every group (would be 'TDA_D5','TDA_U5', and 'TD_BASE' in this case, since i don't want 'ACTUAL' from column A), and use every row of these 4 rows for each group's column C value in an equation with the column C value of 'ACTUAL' from column A.

This means that I would have the equation

```
y = index-5.column-C / index-0.column-C - 1 * 100
```

this equation would repeat for index 6, index 7, and index 8 for the numerator, but the denominator would be index 1, 2, and 3 respectively for the group TDA_D5. This would also then apply to index 19 to 22 as the numerator for group TDA_U5, with denominator still being index 0 to 3, and index 33 to 36 as the numerator for group TD_BASE, and the denominator still as index 0 to 3.

So far I've tried the code

```
a.groupby('A')['C'].apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[0:4] / 100)).reset_index()
```

I'm using / 100 because i'm just first trying to test if I could apply the first 4 records of every group to a simple divide by 100 formula, as I have yet to figure out how to apply it against the actual group's first 4 records in the equation i've mentioned above. I was able to use this piece of code to obtain a series object and have the first four records of every group, including 'ACTUAL' group, to divide by 100, but this is where i'm now stuck. I don't know how I would go about implementing the eventual formula i'm trying to achieve, on the subset of 4 records from every group in A except the 'ACTUAL' group.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show your intended result for the above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not that far.

```
df[df.A != 'ACTUAL'].groupby('A').apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(
                                 (x.iloc[:4].reset_index()['C']/df.iloc[:4]['C'] - 1) * 100))
```

gives:

```
                  C
A                  
TDA_D5  0  1.561400
        1  1.272354
        2  1.100867
        3  0.896263
TDA_U5  0  1.561400
        1  1.890936
        2  2.541661
        3  3.310748
TD_BASE 0  1.561400
        1  1.587185
        2  1.817297
        3  2.068107
```

Or it you prefere to have the labels from column A as columns:

```
df[df.A != 'ACTUAL'].groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x.iloc[:4].reset_index()['C']
                                                   /df.iloc[:4]['C'] - 1) * 100).T
```

which gives:

```
A    TDA_D5    TDA_U5   TD_BASE
C                              
0  1.561400  1.561400  1.561400
1  1.272354  1.890936  1.587185
2  1.100867  2.541661  1.817297
3  0.896263  3.310748  2.068107
```

---

If you want to bring that back into the original dataframe, it is slightly more complex because you will have to keep the original indices. You can do:

```
actual = df[df.A == 'ACTUAL']

out = df[df.A != 'ACTUAL'].groupby('A').apply(
    lambda x: x.iloc[:len(actual)].assign(
        resul=((x.iloc[:len(actual)].reset_index()['C']/
                actual.reset_index()['C'] -1)*100).values)).reset_index(
                    level=0, drop=True)
```

It gives:

```
          A           B           C         D     resul
5    TDA_D5  2019-03-01  253.393661  0.038667  1.561400
6    TDA_D5  2019-06-01  254.329314  0.038229  1.272354
7    TDA_D5  2019-09-01  254.784295  0.038974  1.100867
8    TDA_D5  2019-12-01  254.988064  0.040149  0.896263
9    TDA_D5  2020-03-01  255.158740  0.041696  0.397697
19   TDA_U5  2019-03-01  253.393661  0.038667  1.561400
20   TDA_U5  2019-06-01  255.882782  0.036118  1.890936
21   TDA_U5  2019-09-01  258.415239  0.034246  2.541661
22   TDA_U5  2019-12-01  261.090022  0.032766  3.310748
23   TDA_U5  2020-03-01  264.033754  0.031713  3.889763
33  TD_BASE  2019-03-01  253.393661  0.038667  1.561400
34  TD_BASE  2019-06-01  255.119961  0.037143  1.587185
35  TD_BASE  2019-09-01  256.589769  0.036490  1.817297
36  TD_BASE  2019-12-01  257.949582  0.036184  2.068107
37  TD_BASE  2020-03-01  259.351461  0.036187  2.047414
```

And you can now put that back into the original dataframe thanks to the index:

```
df.loc[out.index, 'resul'] = out['resul']
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the help! This is exactly what I was looking for, may I ask what the reset_index() is achieving here? Also, if I was to insert the result back into the original dataframe to replace the records that were used for the calculation, would I do a join or is there an easier way? I think I would have to somehow retain column B for me to join the records back, since now there's no information from column B to indicate what date period these records belong to now. Thank you so much!!

Comment: `reset_index` causes the group dataframe to get a range(4) index instead of the original row indices. This is required to allow the operation with `df[iloc[:-4]` (ie the 4 first rows of df) because Series must have same index.

Comment: That make sense! Any idea how I might be able to try and bring the result back into the original dataframe, and replace the numerator rows used for the calculation?

Comment: wow that looks super complicated but awesome at the same time, totally ready to try it and digest all of it! But what is actual? It's returning unassigned for me, since I don't see anywhere that the variable actual gets an assignment.

Comment: @RogerLuo: My bad. I forgot to write it in the answer. Post edited

Comment: Dang dude you are awesome, thank you! That's what I was looking for, have a good day!