# update some rows of a given column, based on operations from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My apologies if the title is not fully explicative (I don't even know how to describe the situation in one sentence!). I will be glad to change it if there are good suggestions.

I have a dataframe like this

| country | city | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Country 1 | City 1 | 10178 |
| Country 1 | City 2 | 6918 |
| Country 1 | City 3 | 30540 |
| Country 1 | City 4 | 7832 |
| Country 2 | City 1 | 15104 |
| Country 2 | City 2 | 17408 |
| Country 2 | City 3 | 47321 |
| Country 3 | City 1 | 29313 |
| Country 3 | City 1 | 24905 |
| Country 4 | City 1 | 18866 |
| Country 4 | City 2 | 41307 |
| Country 4 | City 3 | 8122 |
| Country 4 | City 4 | 28912 |
| Country 4 | City 5 | 39079 |
| Country 4 | City 1 | 6660 |
| Country 4 | City 2 | 39953 |
| Country 4 | City 3 | 42214 |

And I want to add a column with the proportion of the national population for each city (assuming those cities are the only ones in that hypothetical country). It would look like this:
[image]

This means that I need to

- add a 4th column named 'relative population' or similar
- get the sum of the population for each country
- in each cell of the new column, the number should be the population of the current row divided by the total population of the current country.

I have seen other related questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570453/how-to-utilize-groupby-perform-calculation-on-only-certain-rows-and-keep-all-co)), and feel that this is close to what I need, but I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to avoid using a loop to go through **each row of the entire dataframe**, because I expect there is a better, more pythonic way (please don't discuss this, it's not the point).

I have tried using this:

```
# calculate the total population of a given country
def TotalPop(thiscountry):
    return df[df['country'] == thiscountry]['population'].sum()

# obtain the list of countries 
countries_list = df['country'].unique()

for country in countries_list:
    df['population_Relative'] = df[df['country'] == country]['population'] / TotalPop(country)
```

---

The problem is that my code above creates the right numbers in the `population_Relative` column **but only for the country in question during the loop, while the other rows are turned into `NaN`**. For example when `country` is `'Country 1'` the relative population column is calculated correctly for each city of Country 1, but then in the next iteration (when `country` is `'Country 2'`), the values of `population_relative` belonging to `'Country 1'` are turned into `NaN`.

How can I achieve the results without affecting the rest of the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby_transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to broadcast the sum to each row. Finally divide population of each city by the population sum:

```
df['population_Relative'] = df['population'] / df.groupby('country')['population'].transform(sum)
print(df)

# Output
      country   city   population  population_Relative
0   Country 1  City 1       10178             0.183493
1   Country 1  City 2        6918             0.124721
2   Country 1  City 3       30540             0.550588
3   Country 1  City 4        7832             0.141199

4   Country 2  City 1       15104             0.189195
5   Country 2  City 2       17408             0.218055
6   Country 2  City 3       47321             0.592750

7   Country 3  City 1       29313             0.540651
8   Country 3  City 1       24905             0.459349

9   Country 4  City 1       18866             0.083807
10  Country 4  City 2       41307             0.183495
11  Country 4  City 3        8122             0.036080
12  Country 4  City 4       28912             0.128433
13  Country 4  City 5       39079             0.173597
14  Country 4  City 1        6660             0.029585
15  Country 4  City 2       39953             0.177480
16  Country 4  City 3       42214             0.187524
```